# Graphic pieChart with MPAndroidChart with image

Tags: java, android

I would like to make the next graphic with `MPAndroidChart`, but the pie chart is not possible to add an image, then someone knows how to add it's

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ODBLE.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MPAndroidChart you can add drawable icon as a label. Here is sample how to add drawable.

```
List<PieEntry> entries = new ArrayList<>();
Drawable icon = ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), R.drawable.name);
// Set the drawable icon to piechart
entries.add(new PieEntry(18.5f, icon));
PieDataSet set = new PieDataSet(entries, "Election Results");
PieData data = new PieData(set);
pieChart.setData(data);
```